# Streaming Data into bigquery only returns partial data

Tags: google-bigquery

I am streaming data into bigquery and the logs are recording no issues at all, when I run "SELECT * FROM `datatable` WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP("2018-11-05") LIMIT 1000" it only returns 16 rows, the row data keeps changing as new data flows in, but it only returns 16 rows.

The Streaming buffer statistics show that there are rows in the buffer.

I started the stream almost 10 hours ago so I would assume there would be some data that I could access.

I am at a bit of a loss here as I cant see errors

This is some sample data that was collected

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Svm6cDWzSvD0RHGo_O5J16UDvqFfDAK5irNki5nYtos/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you provide details on how are you streaming the data? I would like to verify that you are not constantly overriding the first 16 lines.

Comment: I am using this [link](https://github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/ga-bq-stream)

Comment: It seems to overwrite, the Streaming buffer statistics keeps showing the actual rows being inserted in the logs, but the actual table stays the same.

Comment: The fact that some data are in Streaming Buffer and not yet in tables should be irrelevant.  This is internal and the data should be queried as soon as they are inserted (into Streaming buffer or table).

- For details of querying partitioned tables
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-
partitioned-tables

- For some time data may stay in __UNPARTITIONED__ partition
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#ingestion-time_partitioned_tables_95_unpartitioned_partition

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability):

> when streaming to a partitioned table, data in the streaming buffer has a NULL value for the _PARTITIONTIME pseudo column.

You should change your filter to:

```
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME IS NULL OR _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP "2018-11-05"
```

This will include data for the specified date as well as date that is currently in the streaming buffer.

Comment: I have tried that but the issue still exists, I can see the data coming in, but then it drops off at the 16th row.I am using Mark Edmondson ga-bq-stream - https://github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/ga-bq-stream

Comment: Without more details it's difficult to provide meaningful advice. I don't know what "drops off" means in this context or how you are seeing data coming in. Consider updating your question to be more specific.

Comment: In the logs I can see that the rows are successfully inserted with a unique user ID. When I query bigquery I can see that specific row appearing. But as new entries are inserted that row disappears. The max rows just stays at 16, the table does not increase as new entries are added.